# reload jsp page from servlet

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, servlets

I have a jsp page with a table. Every row of the table call a servlet that delete value from that row. Now I have to recall from servlet the same jsp page but I have to reload that for show the update. How can I do that??

this is the jsp calling servlet code

```
<tr class="row" data-href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/adminServlet>
        <td><c:out value="${product.id}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${product.name}" /></td>
        <td><c:out value="${product.cost}" /></td> 
</tr>
```

and this is how I recall jsp page from servlet

```
RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("admin.jsp");    
rd.include(request,response);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax for this problem. Load table data in a jsp as a response from the servlet.

Comment: the problem is that I have to refresh after servlet update...I don't known how to do this..

Comment: on click of delete make an ajax call to servlet for deleting that row and the response should be jsp page from the servlet having table.